# How to manage elements (1st fixed width, 2nd content-related width, 3rd the rest) so they fit together within a given overall width

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I want to arrange three elements (cells or divs) next to each other.
All elements together should have a width of 1000px.
The first element has a fixed width of 200px.
The second has varying width but should be "ungreedy".
The third element is greedy and should fill the rest of the space.

I have approached this problem with a table but haven't had success.
Any Ideas?

Comment: so the second and third have variable width?

Comment: Do the elements have to be equal height?

Comment: the two have variable width just ungreedy and greedy. all have equal height.

Comment: Additional Info: Element 1 and 3 are just for background purposes whereas element 2 has actual content. I can't however render the background behind element 2 because I use semi transparent images and they add to each other.

Comment: Is there minimum width for the element 3 or can no.2 be so wide that no.3 hides completely?

Comment: there is no minimum width. though element 2 won't become big enough to make element 3 vanish.

Comment: Ok. What is the max width for element no.2?

Comment: Can we get a working demo by any chance? My initial thought is that you're overcomplicating the markup and that a solution could be available using only two divs, with the first 200px being set as padding in the first.

Comment: How does the 2nd element's width vary? Because of the width of text inside? Because of JavaScript? Because distinct pages have different content widths?

Comment: http://testyajrs.comlu.com/main.html the 2nd will vary due to the text inside, and due to language support.

Comment: Is your question about the header items? Why won't you simply align language selection to left, login form to right, and the text into the middle (with max width)? Much simpler and easy to do. I don't think it's possible to do what you're after at the moment.

Comment: no its about the menu. bg(black shadow) - menu - bg(black shadow)

Comment: Ah ok. Is the background same on both sides? Are you after a gradient bacground here?

Comment: its an image width black-to transparent gradient. my problem is that i want to make the menu stay on top of the page when scrolling down. so i cant add the background under the menu, then add white, then add the menu. cause then white would scroll with the page. i hope one can understand this o_O

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. Could you draw a sketch image with Photoshop to illustrate?

Comment: I want the menu to scroll with the page. i.e. if I have a very long text and scroll down, the menu scrolls down aswell. if that wasn't the case i could use one div with gradient as bg-image (with a bg-color) spreading to full width. and a second one in it with the same bg-color (which hides the gradient) and the menu on top. if i let that scroll down however its not all transparent (which i want) because the bg-color under the menu also scrolls down. i cant sketch this... hope you understand now. and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I do not guarantee the good result, but:

```
#enclosing { width: 1000px }
#first { width: 200px; max-width: 200px }
#second { width: 1px }
```

may give a good results in a table.

Comment: Does not work. The content of element 2 is broken into several lines.

Comment: Well, that's another problem then. A lot harder, I would say,if you want the content in second not to be split... splitting is pretty natural in HTML. I am curious if the solution ever exists.